# Mongoengine integer id, and User creating

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine, nosql

1. MongoDB is using string(hash) _id field instead of integer; so, how to get classic id primary key? Increment some variable each time I create my class instance?

   ```
   class Post(Document):
       authors_id = ListField(IntField(required=True), required=True)
       content = StringField(max_length=100000, required=True)
       id = IntField(required=True, primary_key=True)

       def __init__(self):
           //what next?
   ```
2. Trying to create new user raises exception:

   ```
   mongoengine.queryset.OperationError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys 
   (E11000 duplicate key error index: test.user.$_types_1_username_1
    dup key: { : "User", : "admin" })
   ```

Code:

```
user = User.create_user(username='admin', email='example@mail.com',
                        password='pass')
user.is_superuser = True
user.save()
```

Why?

Comment: Split your questions to two posts because they are unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `SequenceField` which you could use to provide this.  But as stated incrementing id's dont scale well and are they really needed?  Can't you use `ObjectId` or a slug instead?

Comment: Haha, I don't know how can I miss it. Big thanks, it's what i really need.

Comment: Good stuff, dont forget to mark the question as answered to help others in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an incrementing integer ID, the method to do it is described here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field

This won't scale for a vary large DB/app but it works well for small or moderate application.

Comment: Thanks! 

It would be my little blog :)

Answer (score 0):

1) If you really want to do it you have to override the mongoengine method saving your documents, to make it look for one document with the highest value for your id and save the document using that id+1. This will create overhead (and one additional read every write), therefore I discourage you to follow this path. You could also have issues of duplicated IDs (if you save two records at the exactly same time, you'll read twice the last id - say 1 and save twice the id 1+1 = 2 => that's really bad - to avoid this issue you'd need to lock the entire collection at every insert, by losing performances).

2) Simply you can't save more than one user with the same username (as the error message is telling you) - and you already have a user called "admin".

Comment: 1) Do you have any other ways? I just wan't to use it like site/post/50
2) Yeah, solved

Comment: go for the internally generated mogoid! or switch to mysql if you really want to use incremental ids ;)

Comment: you wouldn't need to lock the entire collection you're inserting into, you just need to keep the incrementing key in its own collection.  See my answer for link.